# Meaning of the word: "предоставление"

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I am using slovar (book) and the auto-translate resources but can not narrow down what: "предоставление" means in this context. Is money involved in this or is it a loan?

This sentence comes supposedly from a "перечень" at a train.

"предоставление постельного белья"

2) "застилка и уборка постелей". I am curious what: "застилка" means in this context. If it is to clean, to cover or to make the bed? What is the most appropriate in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`предоставление` in this context would be `delivery`, i.e. bed linen delivery.

`застилка (постели)` would be to make a bed in the evening (before going to sleep), `уборка (постели)` is to make a bed in the morning (when you get up).
Just to elaborate more on that, there are corresponding verbs for that as well `застелить постель/кровать` and `убрать постель/кровать`.

Comment: Highly appreciated for added the elaboration on this. Very good to know.

Comment: _Застилать постель_ means covering the bed after you get up, not before you go to sleep! However, I have no idea why _уборка постели_ is separately mentioned in this text, because it's actually the same... To make the bed before going to sleep is _**по**стелить (постель)_.

Comment: @Alex.S well, then you actually could use `застилать` both ways in the morning and in the evening. `постелить` also could be used in the evening, but that doesn't require the noun (постель). I've just asked my wife and she uses exactly `застилать/убирать` pair the way I described it, because `застилать` literally means to cover with _new, clean_ linen

Answer (score 2):

предоставить is the official-style word meaning "to give", "to provide".

So, предоставление is giving.

Answer (score 1):

These are nominalizations of verbs, so `застилка` постели regards the process (or result, either way a noun) of bed-making.

The difference between застилка and уборка, especially when compared in one sentence like this, can be that the former is about making the bed (putting on the linen) and the latter can be un-making it (clearing out the bedsheets and matresses, so it can be a sitting location during the day).